# Disabling flash[:notice] to make page caching make sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We make heavy use of page caching, and sometimes pages get cached with a *"You are now signed in"* message. We can't disable the page caching for logged in users, or make it unique to them. So the only option I can think of is to disable the flash when a page is being cached, or visa-versa, disable caching when the flash is set. Idealy with will be done in one place, so we can't accidentally do it again.

Is this possible?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up dynamic page caching. Uses Javascript/Ajax to update signed in messages:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching